# Have done (habitual) + finite purpose clause. What is the tense of the purpose clause?

Tags: grammar

What will be the tense if the purpose is expressed by a finite clause in

*I have gone to bed early since last week to wake up early*.

Comment: The sentence isn't natural. Something like this would be better: *I have been going to bed early every night for the past week so that I could wake up early.*

Comment: But, in your sentence, *to wake up* is the infinitive, and it doesn't have a tense.

Comment: Can we say "...so that I wake up early"?

Comment: That's possible too.